# Disable Past Dates using DatePicker by 'Stefan Petre'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Due to some restriction I have to use DatePicker written by Stefan Petre and I need to be able to disable past dates, you can find implementation of his DatePicker here: http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

According to him, I would be able to disable dates onRender function but appreantly this would disable all dates:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(-1);
onRender : function(){
           return{
                disabled : date < new Date()
           };
        }
```

Have you previously worked with this custom DatePicker library? if so your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem just now, it seems startDate or minDate doesn't work for this specific datepicker.

For **jQuery UI** datepickers, you may use " `minDate: 0` " to disable all past dates.

For the **forked** version of Stefan Petre's datepicker, you may use " `startDate: 0` " to disable all past dates.

But as for this one, the original Stefan Petre's datepicker, which he doesn't seem to actively contribute to at the moment, you may use the onRender function, like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ //this applies to all elements with the class "datepicker"
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''; //disables all past dates
    },
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd", //sets format of the date displayed after selecting date
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $('.datepicker.dropdown-menu').hide(); //closes the datepicker after selecting date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `OnRender` you can use below code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var now=new Date();
        $('#date').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: '2008-07-31',
        current: '2008-07-31',
        calendars: 1,
        startDate: now,
        starts: 1
    });
});
```